# How can I test if a function is called onChange in a functional React component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple functional component which I need to test.

```
const Product = () => {
    const handleOnChange = (value) => {
        console.log(value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {handleOnChange(e.target.value)}} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'd like to test if "handleOnChange" function is called when the input changes its value. I tried that:

```
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Product />);
});
describe('Product interactions', () => {
it('should call handleOnChange function on input change', () => {

  const mockedhandleOnChange = jest.fn(); 
  wrapper.handleOnChange = mockedhandleOnChange;
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 10}});
  expect(mockedhandleOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);    
});
```

});

Of course it doesn't work as I cannot reach the function via "wrapper.handleOnChange".

Please help!

Comment: `handleOnChange` is a constant declared inside the function, it is not available outside. By the way, usually is better to test that what is inside the function have been called or that the UI itself has changed. In this example you should assert that `console.log` it is called (I know that it is not the real code)

Comment: Emanuele, thank you very much for your comment. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score -1):

```
it('should call handleOnChange function on input change', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Product />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 10 } });
    input = wrapper.find('input');
    expect(input.props().value).toEqual(10);
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

You should make React `state` single source of truth. Currently, `input` in your program is maintaining its own state. Better option would be to use it as [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Once you are using `input` as a controlled component, your program would be something like below:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }
  handleOnChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input id="input1" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => {handleOnChange(e.target.value)}} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Once you have the above code, it will be much simpler to do validation on `input` and also to test. You need to call `onChange` of `input`, after which you can validate state. Your test will look something like below:

```
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(<Product />);
});
describe('Product interactions', () => {
  it('should call handleOnChange function on input change', () => {
    wrapper.find('#input1').getNode().props.onChange({
      target: { value: '123' }
    });
    expect(wrapper.state().value).toEqual('123');
  });
});
```

Comment: Mukesh, thank you very much for your post. It helps me in connection with classes. However I try now to avoid them by using functional components with hooks. This makes testing harder.